# Question about homotopy lifting data definitions

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Consider the following situation for a map $p : E → B$. We are given a
>    homotopy $F : X × I → B$, and a map $g : X → E$ such that, $p ◦ g(x) =
> F(x, 0), ∀ x ∈ X$.  We say $p$ satisfies the homotopy lifting property
>    if
>    **for each homotopy lifting data as above**, there exists a homotopy $G : X × I → E$ with the property $p ◦ G = F$ and $G(x, 0) = g(x), ∀ x
>  ∈ X$

[image]

I have two questions:

$1.$  How can there be multiple homotopy liftng data's?  What exactly represents the set of homotopy lifting data from which you can choose a particular homotopy lifting data? (Referencing the bolded text in the above box)

$2.$  Aren't these graphs incorrect since $g: X \rightarrow E$ and not $g: X \times \{0\} \rightarrow E$?

Comment: Regarding item 2, there is a natural one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $X \times \{0\}$, namely $x \leftrightarrow (x,0)$, and so the ambiguity between the words in the box and the picture is easily resolved. If you would rather not let the ambituity stand, you can fix the words in the box, or the picture, in the obvious way so as to correct the ambiguity.

Comment: Regarding item 1, the homotopy lifting data consists of the two maps $F,g$, subject to the condition that $p \circ g(x)=F(x,0)$. 

Any other pair of maps $F_1,g_1$ that satisfy the condition $p \circ g_1(x) = F_1(x,0)$ may also be regarded as homotopy lifting data. The pair $F,g$ is equal to the pair $F_1,g_1$ if and only if we have equality of functions $F=F_1$ and $g=g_1$ (this is exactly the same as equality of ordered pairs where the two entries in the ordered pair are functions). So, the pair $F,g$ is different from the pair $F_1,g_1$ if and only if $F \ne F_1$ or $g \ne g_1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher How would you re-draw the graph to include the $X$ and $X \times \{0\}$ relationship?

Comment: I would change $X \times \{0\}$ to $X$ and I would change $\eta$ from the inclusion map to the map $\eta(x)=(x,0)$.

Comment: So then wouldn't you have to restate the first part as $p \circ g(x) = F \circ \eta (x)$?

Comment: You could do so if you wished, although it would be unnecessary to do so, because $\eta(x)=(x,0)$ if you did that change.